# Javascript Error: Cannot Convert Object to Primitive Value

Tags: javascript, object, primitive

I'm receiving this error using the following javascript code:

```js
function tempTest(evt) {
    alert(evt.currentTarget.id);
    ct = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);
    rslt = document.getElementById('rslt');
    var props;
    for (var prop in ct) {
        if (ct.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            propVal = ct[prop];
            var propDat = prop + ' = ' + propVal;
            props += propDat + '<br/>';
        }
    }
    rslt.innerHTML = props;
}
```

This one has me puzzled. Any ideas?

Comment: var propDat = prop + ' = ' + propVal;

Comment: Same error if I phrase it as: var propDat = prop + ' = ' + ct[prop]; and ditch propVal.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through the property of the element in question. In this case, it's an <a> element, but I'll eventually be using this for divs, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all the properties of a HTML element are primitives. for example, parent, childs etc are also HTML elements. You can't just use them as strings or numbers.
You need to add there a condition and use that property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to add a condition to check for string values and act on that. This is sufficient for what I'm doing with this snippet.

Answer (score 5):

If the object in question is json, you can call `JSON.stringify(thingThatIsJson)` which will return a String. `.toString()` does not work on json.

This is a message to those of you dealing with something like `req.body` which will work in `console.log()` which is rather confusing since it may not otherwise behave like a String (like when you're trying to add it to another String).

Answer (score 2):

***(The OP:)***

> Just wanted to post the updated snippet for anyone who stumbles onto this post...

```js
function tempTest(evt) {
    alert(evt.currentTarget.id);
    ct = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id);
    rslt = document.getElementById('rslt');
    var props;
    for (var prop in ct) {
        if (ct.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var propVal = ct[prop];
            props += prop + ' (' + typeof(prop) + ')' + ' = ';
            if (typeof(ct[prop]) == 'string') {
                propVal += ct[prop];
            } else {
                if (propVal != null && propVal.toString) {
                    props += propVal.toString();
                } else {}
            }
            props += '<br/>';
        }
    }
    rslt.innerHTML = props;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the `propVal` part of your code. Since that may not be converted into a string.